# Usage of "measurable" in measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Why are measurable functions called "measurable"? What exactly is being "measured"?

For measurable sets, I can intuitively understand that the measure of the set "measures" how large is the set.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The short answer is "nothing is being measured, certainly not the function."  The term  *measurable function*   is used frequently in situations where there is no measure at all.  Similarly *measurable space* is used without any measure or anything being measured. *Measurable cardinals* can be defined relative to a "measure" but not one that would make you happy.  Generally the connection between the mathematical meaning of a word and the dictionary meaning of that word in the vernacular can be very vague or nonexistent.  Do not seek for intuition about concepts from the word choice itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a measurable function $f$, we can measure what is $\{f \leq 1\}$ or what is $\{0.5\leq f\leq 12\}$ etc.

Comment: Sorry Ilya, but I think that is a bit silly.  You can "measure" any set.  Every set has a precise Lebesgue outer measure and a Lebesgue inner measure.  A set is "measurable" when the two measures agree not when "it *can be measured*."   Call it "Lebegueable" instead!  Then a function is Lebesgueable when these sets $\{f\leq a\}$ are "Lebesgueable".  Not "when it can be Lebesgued!"

Comment: @B.S.Thomson you have rectifiable curves, you have measurable sets - that all has a practical motivation for the terminology. That extends to related notions, e.g. to measurable functions. I see no motivation I call my idea silly. It's borderline impolite.

Comment: Sorry don't take offence.  The question is a bit silly since it implies a connection between the mathematical definition of the word "measurable" and the English language equivalent "able to be measured".  Similarly "rectifiable" has a nice mathematical definition, but I would discourage any student who thinks it is connected with "able to be rectified".  In English "rectify" means: (i) to set right (ii) to purify (as alcohol) especially by repeated or fractional distillation or (iii)  to correct by removing errors.

Comment: Here's a nonmathematical analogy.  I'm sure there are words in Dutch that simply cannot be translated into a brief English phrase (like *Torschlusspanik* in German).  The  Dutch-English dictionary phrase book may help with your intuition a bit, but eventually you must learn the precise meaning and how it is used.  Similarly "measurable" for mathematics.   We can explain why Lebesgue thought it was a good word to convey the meaning, but it is generally a waste of time to try to tease meaning out of the word itself, rather than the definition.  That is merely my point.

Answer (score 4):

1. What is so "real" about the real numbers?
2. Why  is an open set called "open?"
3. Why are Cauchy sequences called "Cauchy?"
4. Why are Lipschitz functions called "Lipschitz?"
5. Why is $e$ called "e?"
6. Why are compact sets called "compact?"
7. Why are monotonic sequences called "monotonic?" [monotonic=speaking
   or uttered with an unchanging pitch or tone.]
8. Why are some metric spaces "separable?"
9. Why are some sets "barrelled?"
10. Why do we say some sets are "G-delta" and others are "F-sigma?"

I could go on, ... but I won't!  The answer is always  *historical*. If the word choice makes some sense in context then you are lucky.  In English *measurable="able to be measured"* but mathematicians are under no obligation to choose language that makes sense in the vernacular.

Lebesgue probably took the language from the earlier Peano-Jordan theory of measure.  Since he called, both sets and functions, *measurable* we are stuck with the language.  Associate the term directly with the actual definition, not with any intuitive or suggestive meaning.

For the others in this list, some were named this way after famous mathematicians.  The "open set" one is stranger:  they first defined what a closed set was and declared that "open" meant "not closed" [like doors and windows].  Eventually the term acquired its current meaning which is very very different from "not closed" [to the dismay of some of my students].

The explanation for "G-delta" and "F-sigma" is curious: in French closed is *ferme* and sum is *somme* hence the $F_\sigma$.   In German the words for open/intersection  are *Gebiet* and *Durchshnitt* and that is why we use $G_\delta$.

In short if you feel like asking this kind of question, well ask away!  But be prepared for a completely unsatisfying answer that amounts to nothing more that "that is what we always call them."

Answer (score 1):

Measuable functions preserve sigma-algebra structure i.e measurable sets.

Answer (score 1):

An integral is, at heart, a limit of sums of the form "value of the function times size of the region".

The idea behind the Lebesgue integral of a real function $f$ on a region $L\subset\mathbb R$, that addresses shortcomings in the Riemann integral, is to divide the codomain into small intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ and take the limit of sums of the form
$$\tag1
\sum_j t_j\,m(f^{-1}(I_j)),
$$
where $t_j\in I_j$, $j=1,\ldots,n$. For this to make sense one needs to extend the notion of "length" from intervals (as used in the Riemann integral) to arbitrary sets. This turns out to be impossible if we want our *measure* $m$ to have reasonable properties. Lebesgue and others realized that one can still define $m$ if instead of considering every possible subset of $\mathbb R$ one restrict to a certain family of subsets, thus called *measurable* sets. The family of Lebesgue-measurable sets is big enough to cover almost any reasonable set that arises naturally.

The problem is that now, in $(1)$, $f^{-1}(I_j)$ cannot be any set, but rather it has to be a set where $m$ makes sense, i.e., a measurable set. So the Lebesgue integral will work only for functions where $f^{-1}(I)$ is measurable for every interval $I$. Such functions are call *measurable*, in the sense that their preimages of intervals are measurable.