# Why are $F_\sigma$-sets and $G_\delta$-sets called that way?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying $F_\sigma$-sets and $G_\delta$-sets and I'm having trouble remembering which is which and keep mixing them up. I think it's because the notation seems arbitrary to me. Why are $F_\sigma$-sets and $G_\delta$-sets called that way?

> **Definition**. A set $F$ is called an $F_\sigma$-set (or an $F_\sigma$) if it is the union of at most countably many closed sets. A set $G$ is called a $G_\delta$ if it is the intersection of at most countably many open sets.

Definition from Topology by James Dugundji.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1526289/

Comment: Page 4 [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi9-Ynn3b73AhWSKUQIHWPpDiQQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.etsu.edu%2Fgardnerr%2F5210%2Fnotes%2F1-4.pdf&usg=AOvVaw14HDaaN-nvlvfQ1Fz-Rvjc) gives a possible reason. This wiki pages are [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set) and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set).

Comment: My post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4434268/861687 last question.

Comment: As others have indicated (by links), the letters are due to French words for open and closed. Before I fully internalized the notation and didn't have to resort to a [mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic), I matched 'G' with open because 'G' looked more like a circle/disk (open sets go with open balls) and 'F' with closed because 'F' looked more like a rigid figure made of line segments (thus closed, but not open). And I knew $\sigma$ was for unions (from $\sigma$-algebras), plus you don't get anything new by taking unions of open sets or by taking intersections of closed sets.

Comment: English mnemonic  F for "Full" and $\sigma$ (Greek "s") for "sum". i.e. "union".